# media query not woking properly

Tags: html, css

There is media query for 900px - after that, links in main-nav become positioned absolute without any relative parent and should take 100% width and height with a  blue background. Everything seems to be working except the hamburger button in the top right corner still appears, and I'd like it to be hidden.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  /* font-size: 10px; */
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #555;
}


/* 000000reuse0000000000000000000000 */

.container {
  max-width: 120rem;
  padding: 0 3.2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 9.6rem;
  column-gap: 6.4rem;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fdf2e9;
  height: 9.6rem;
  padding: 0 4.8rem;
}

.logo {
  height: 2.2rem;
}


/* navvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv */


/* navigation */

.main-nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 4.8rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-nav-link:link,
.main-nav-link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  transition: all 0.3;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav-link:hover,
.main-nav-link:active {
  color: #cf711f;
}

.main-nav-link.nav-cta:link,
.main-nav-link.nav-cta:visited {
  padding: 1.2rem 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 9px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.main-nav-link.nav-cta:hover,
.main-nav-link.nav-cta:active {
  background-color: #cf711f;
}


/* mobie vie b */

.btn-mobile-nav {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-mobile-nav {
  height: 4.8rem;
  width: 4.8rem;
  color: #333;
}

@media (max-width: 59em) {
  html {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
  /* mobile nav */
  .main-nav {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .main-nav-list {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 4.8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
  <title>omnifood</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="logo" alt="omn logo" src="img/omnifood-logo.png" />
    </a>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">How it works</a></li>
        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Meals</a></li>
        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="main-nav-link nav-cta" href="#">Try for free</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="btn-mobile-nav">
        <ion-icon class="icon-mobile-nav" name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be working as expected. If you click the blue "Run code snippet" button at the bottom of your embedded code, then you can click "Expand snippet" and change the width of your browser to see it. Could you explain in more detail what doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: but the three line button on right should also be hidden behind blue color

Comment: You need to add a `z-index` property to your `.main-nav` in your media query. The query works just fine. A position of `absolute` doesn't automatically place things "above" other elements. Try `z-index: 5;`

Comment: fine with positive z-index it will hide the button but can you explain why at first place  the button even showing it shouldn't.

Comment: Ah, I see now - it's just the hamburger icon you want hidden on mobile? You're not currently hiding it in any way. Adding `.btn-mobile-nav { display:none; }` inside your media query should do it.

Comment: yeah but why the icon is not hidden because it should what's the reason

Comment: the reason is that you're not currently hiding it in your CSS anywhere. Please re-read my previous comment.